# Does the ECB issue staff projections for its own interest rates, as the Fed does?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, monetary-policy, forecasting, euro-area

I can see that it has a 'projections' segment here:
[ECB staff forecast](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/projections/html/index.en.html)

But it seems to take market rates as reference.